# Change number format thousands to K

Tags: flutter, dart, number-formatting

```
Text(
       '${NumberFormat.compactSimpleCurrency(
           decimalDigits: 0).format(docSnap['count'])} searches',
```

Can you help me how to convert number for example 10,000 to 10K but without currency sign like $ or etc. it is because i just want to show only 10k instead of $10k

Comment: create custom function.

Comment: can you help me how?

Comment: convert_num(String input){
      int val = int.parse(input);
       print(val);
      if(val < 1000){
          return val;
      }else if(val >= 1000 && val <= 100000){
          return (val/1000).toString()+" K";
          print(val);
      }
      return val;
   }
   print(convert_num("10000"));

Comment: just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the `intl package` -->
https://pub.dev/packages/intl

Create custom function like this,

```
String formatNumber(int number) {
    return NumberFormat.compact().format(number);
  }
```

Call the `formatNumber` function when you want it.

---

How to use this with Text Widget,

```
int number = 100000; // Variable
Text(formatNumber(number),) // call the function inside Text widget
```

Comment: sorry, one more thing i want to ask. how to combine both NumberFormat.compact() and NumberFormat.decimalDigits() ?